# Can ping to other router subnet but cannot ping host to host

Tags: networking, virtualization, routing, ping

Using VMware, I set 2 hosts connected through a router.
All 3 virtual computers run Ubuntu 14.10.

- Host A (eth2: 192.168.1.11/24)
- Router (eth2: 192.168.1.12/24) (eth3: 192.168.3.2/24)
- Host B (eth2: 192.168.3.1/24)

My setup has the following symptoms:

- Host A can ping 192.168.3.2, but cannot ping Host B (100% packet loss).
- Host B can ping 192.168.1.12, but cannot ping Host A (Destination Host Unreachable).
- Router can ping both hosts.

What I have done or tried so far:

- I have enabled IP forwarding (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`).
- I have added both hosts statically in the router's routing table.
- I did nothing on IP masquerading, since the hosts are within private networks only.

Why can't the hosts ping each other?

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours, I solved the problem.

Host A:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.12
route del default gw 192.168.1.11
```

Host B:

```
route add default gw 192.168.3.2
route del default gw 192.168.3.1
```